# How does the CGI cookie work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cookies, cgi

This is the example I keep seeing online as how to set cookies.

```
require "cgi"
cookie = CGI::Cookie.new("rubyweb", "CustID=123", "Part=ABC");
cgi = CGI.new("html3")
cgi.out( "cookie" => [cookie] ){
  cgi.html{
    "\nHTML content here"
  }
}
```

I tried doing it this way and it sets the cookie and then comes up with a blank page.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'
load 'inc_game.cgi'
cgi = CGI.new

cookie = CGI::Cookie.new("rubyweb", "CustID=123", "Part=ABC");
cgi.out( "cookie" => [cookie] ){""}     

#see if game submit buttons pressed
doIt = cgi['play']
puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"  

play = Game.new

#welcome
if doIt == ''
puts play.displayGreeting
end

#choose weapon
play.playGame

if doIt == 'Play'
    move = cgi['weapon']
    human = play.humanMove(move)
    computer = play.ComputerMove
    print human
    print computer
    result = play.results(human,computer)
    play.displayResults(result)
end
```

So my question first would be, what am I missing/doing wrong?  Secondly I am wondering if anyone would want to explain what .out does as opposed to .header or if there is a difference?

Thanks,

Levi

Comment: From reading a bit more I found out that cgi.out handles much of what cgi.header would.  So it is just a more concise way to control output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this line:

```
cgi.out( "cookie" => [cookie] ){""}
```

Is flushing your headers out.

Upon running the code bare in my TTY,

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: rubyweb=CustID%3D123&Part%3DABC; path=

Content-type: text/html
```

was emitted, and "Content-Length: 0" ( generated by the empty string in out{}  )  is possibly telling the browser you're done.

```
cookie = CGI::Cookie.new("rubyweb", "CustID=123", "Part=ABC");
cgi.header( "cookie" => [cookie] ,  type => 'text/html' )

#normal printing here
```

Would be preferable for sending headers.

Opting for  a 'do processing' - 'then think about output' model might help.

```
require 'cgi'
load 'inc_game.cgi'

cgi = CGI.new
cookie = CGI::Cookie.new("rubyweb", "CustID=123", "Part=ABC");

output = ""; 

#see if game submit buttons pressed
doIt = cgi['play']

play = Game.new

#welcome
if doIt == ''
  output << play.displayGreeting
end

#choose weapon
play.playGame

if doIt == 'Play'
    move = cgi['weapon']
    human = play.humanMove(move)
    computer = play.ComputerMove
    output << human
    output << computer
    result = play.results(human,computer)
    output << play.displayResults(result)
end



cgi.out( "cookie" => [cookie] , type=>"text/html" ){ 
  output; 
}
```

Comment: Sending the header caused an internal server error, this is the option that would work best for me though.  Sending the output at the end also causes an internal server error, most likely because I am printing text out in the main body and the print content isn't set until the end

Comment: Consider it a design error at least then. Its really not a good idea ( generally ) to have print statements deep in random code

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind.  Do you have any idea as to why the header would throw an internal server error in your first suggestion?  I am sending it before anything is printed.

Comment: it depends on your server, you'll want to check your specific servers internal error logs and see its explanation for why it ISE'd, it could be one of dozens of reasons, one being early  termination because of invalid code.